# Random row breaks in CSV read with php

Tags: php, excel, csv, import

I am trying to read and display the content of a CSV file. For some reason it bugs out with this file I am trying to read.

This is my code.

```
<?php
if (($handle = fopen("http://testdummies.dk/csv/weird2.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    echo "<pre>";
            print_r ($data);
            echo "</pre>";

}
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

I use a danish CSV file so it uses ; instead of ,!

I have made this test at http://testdummies.dk/csv/testdups2.php

The first 3 arrays it generates are correct, but the 4th breaks out at "cell" 47. I just cant figure out why. (the file opens fine in excel).

The file is at http://testdummies.dk/csv/weird2.csv

Thanks in advance.

René

Comment: Is there a stray unescaped `;` in the cell, or the cell after?

Comment: There sadly isnt a ; in the whole file (except those between the rows).

Comment: The 47th cell has two newlines in it. It's quoted, so I think that's supposed to protect the newlines, but maybe PHP doesn't recognize that.

Comment: @Resin01 I see lots of `;` in the file. The first line is `PRODUCTS;dsdadsdsa;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;dsad;hejmor`

Comment: varekurv og 5-punktssele. Ryggen kan indstilles til hvileposition, ca. 30 grader. Frontbøjle tilkøbes.<BR>Dimensioner sammenklappet: 113 x 28 x 24 cm.<BR><BR></FONT>Anbefalet alder 6m - 3+ år </P><P> </P> - you have newline after </p>, so it's starting again with array

Comment: metalfight - Any idea why it gets that? If I open the file in excel it doesnt read it as a newline. Notepad doesnt seem to read it as a newline either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [blog post](http://minghong.blogspot.com/2006/07/csv-parser-for-php.html) says that PHP `fgetcsv()` doesn't handle quoted newlines properly. He provides his own `CsvFileParser` class that addresses the problem.

Comment: I cant seem to get that to work sadly. I'm not sure it reads my file right :(
require_once("csvparser.php");

$csv = new CsvFileParser;

$data = $csv->ParseFromFile("weird2.csv");

print_r($data); <- This just returns "1"

Comment: Read the documentation comments. `ParseFromFile` just returns a boolean success indicator, not the CSV data. The CSV data is in `$data->data`, which is a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: You also need to assign `$csv->delimiter = ';'`.

Comment: That did it :D $csv->data had the data. All works now! It doesnt handle special chars like æøå, but that I will try to fix myself.. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Barmar for the answer...from that blog post I found a slightly more recent library built off of the CsvFileParser class, with some additional functions.

[ParseCSV](https://github.com/jimeh/php-parsecsv)

For example the ParseCSV library is built to allow for automatically ignoring the header row in a file.  Also the resulting array output seems to be structured a bit more cleanly.