# parse csv in cell with new line using php

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to parse csv file using `fgetcsv` method in php.
problem is that some cell having text which has new line character and because of that 
it breaks all text after new line into other cell's value.
how can i resolve this issue?

my file having following data

```
label,value
identifier_6,"label2323
werffjdnfg
sdfsdfdsfg
dfgdfngdngd"
```

my code is

```
function parse_file($p_Filepath) {

        $file = fopen($p_Filepath, 'r');
        $this->fields = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure);
        $keys_values = explode(',',$this->fields[0]);

        $content    =   array();
        $keys   =   $this->escape_string($keys_values);

        $i  =   0;
        while( ($row = fgetcsv($file, $this->max_row_size, $this->separator, $this->enclosure)) != false ) {            
            if( $row != null ) { // skip empty lines
                $values =   explode(',',$row[0]);

                if(count($keys) == count($values)){
                    $arr    =   array();
                    $new_values =   array();
                    $new_values =   $this->escape_string($values);
                    for($j=0;$j<count($keys);$j++){
                        if($keys[$j] != ""){
                            $arr[$keys[$j]] =   $new_values[$j];
                        }
                    }
                    $content[$i]=   $arr;
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($file);
        $data['keys'] = $keys;
        $data['csvData'] = $content;
        return $data;
    }

    function escape_string($data){
        $result =   array();

        foreach($data as $row){
//            $result[]   =   $row;
            $result[]   =   str_replace('"', '',$row);
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code.?

Comment: text is surrounded with quotes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random row breaks in CSV read with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527317/random-row-breaks-in-csv-read-with-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function get2DArrayFromCsv($file,$delimiter) 
{ 
        if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) { 
            $i = 0; 
            while (($lineArray = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) { 
                for ($j=0; $j<count($lineArray); $j++) { 
                    $data2DArray[$i][$j] = $lineArray[$j]; 
                } 
                $i++; 
            } 
            fclose($handle); 
        } 
        return $data2DArray; 
    } 
    $resList=get2DArrayFromCsv($csv_file, ',');
```

Can you let me know this will help you or not.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built in function for reading CSV: [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

function:

```
function parseCSV($file, $buffer = 1024, $delimiter = ',', $enclosure = '"') {
    $csv_data = array();
    if (file_exists($file) && is_readable($file)) {
        if (($handle = fopen($file, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, $buffer, $delimiter, $enclosure)) !== FALSE) {
                $csv_data[] = $data;
            }
        }
    }
    return $csv_data;
}
```

usage:

```
$csv_data = parseCSV('my_file.csv');
```

`returns assoc array of your CSV file data`

Comment: He said he's using `fgetcsv()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, I works correctly even if your column values contains commas or new line characters

```
<?php
// Set path to CSV file
$csvFile = 'test.csv';
$file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
//fgetcsv($file_handle);//skips the first line while reading the csv file, uncomment this line if you want to skip the first line in csv file
while (!feof($file_handle) )
{
    $csv_data[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
}
fclose($file_handle);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($csv_data);
echo '</pre>';

foreach($csv_data as $data)
{
    echo "<br>column 1 data = ".$data[0];
    echo "<br>column 2 data = ".$data[1];
}
?>
```